# Do I update the state by use of concatenation or do I fetch the updated state from my DB and set my state to that? What is correct?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-reducers

I'm not sure what the best practice is for updating the state inside of a reducer.

Let's say my reducer is a list of blogs. I've created an action, getBlogs, that fetches these blogs on component mount and I created an action, addBlog, that will add a new blog to the blog state.

1. Do I update the blog state by using concatenation like so: blogs: [...state.blogs, newBlog]

or

2. Dispatch getBlogs again to get the now updated state and set blogs to that. This will be called from within addBlog if adding a blog was succesful.

Sorry if this sounds vague. I can't seem to formulate my question properly so I didn't find a good resource on what's correct and what's not.

Comment: Option 1 would be considered an optimistic update. You don't know for sure that your server successfully updated the DB, but you are treating it as if it did. Option 2 is safer, but slower since you must wait for two ajax calls to complete before seeing the update. Not sure if there is a "best practice", just difference strategies for different use-cases.

Comment: I haven't come across the term "optimistic update" but that's really good to know, thank you. Anyway, wouldn't that mean that option 2 will always be the better option purely because it is safer? I can't think of a use-case on the top off my head that would benefit from option 1.

Comment: I pretty much always use option 2. I guess if there is a significant speed gain from option 1, and the risk of server failure is tolerable and not critically important then that would be the use-case. Or if you have robust error handling on the "addBlog" so that a failure also removes it from state again, that would work. But I don't think it should be a very common choice.